# SPA with angular JS node JS and Oracle database

Tags: node.js

I am new to angularjs and node js. I want to connect my angularjs UI to oracle database using nodejs. Is it possible. If yes please help me in this with any example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [the Node.js driver for Oracle Database](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb) (node-oracledb) to create an API that your AngularJS application can consume.

See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQgw2WmyuFM) for some ideas.